# Google map showing error but map showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I know many people faced this type of error because many question & answer related to this type of error

Below is my dynamic footer

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script async src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

custom.js look like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Google Map
    function initMap(){
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: location,
            scrollwheel:false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
        // alert("Google Working");
    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
});
```

Map div only for `contact-us.html` page

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

but the map showing & also showing error like below

```
InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
```

& all pages without contactus.html showing below error on the console

```
TypeError: a is null
...ndChild(c)};_.ug=function(a){for(var b;b=a.firstChild;)_.tg(b),a.removeChild(b)}
```

I'm searching last two days & applying for this but not any helpful answer.

I need to destroy error.

What's wrong with my code.

Thanks

**Edited Based Answer Which Working Now**

```
function initMap(){
 var divId = document.getElementById("map");
 if (!divId) {
    return;
 }

 var location = {lat: 40.712784, lng: -74.005941};
 var map = new google.maps.Map(divId,{
    zoom: 6,
    center: location,
    scrollwheel:false
 });
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
 });
}
```

Load JS

```
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `initMap()` is scoped in anonymous function so googlemaps can't see this function.
You should declare function in global scope without `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ...`

```
function initMap(){
    var div = document.getElementById("map");
    if (!div) {
        return;
    }
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: location,
        scrollwheel:false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(div,
    myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    // alert("Google Working");
};
window.onload = function() {
    if (google) {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
    }
}
```

more about scopes: https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/#what-is-local-scope

Loads libs:

```
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: And the reason why it works despite the error is because after the page loads, you call google.maps.event.addDomListener from within the same scope as initMap.

Comment: @Piotr I have edited based on your instruction but still showing error

Comment: What a brilliant guy  `Piotr` working based your concept,  please see my question, now edited & put the solution based on you & `fool` answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Custom js file link need to go upper then google API link like below

```
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Edit custom js file see below code which working

```
 function initMap(){
  var location = {lat: 40.712784, lng: -74.005941};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
    zoom: 6,
    center: location,
    scrollwheel:false
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
}
```

I hope to help you

Thanks

Comment: Yes that is working for `contact-us.html` I mean removed error from console but all other pages which page not using google map these are showing error `TypeError: a is null` because my footer section is dynamic, how to remove this error from console